# How to POST the String Payload to http localhost in mule?

Tags: http, mule, mule-studio

Am new to Mule and I need to POST the string payload which is stored in a variable to http localhost. Below is my configuration.

```
<flow name="RequestFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">
        <set-variable variableName="variable1" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Set Request"/>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" doc:name="Web Service Consumer" operation="Submit"/>
        <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
</flow>
```

I need to do the POST call before consuming web service.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, you have the following URL-
localhost:8081/getDetails?country=india

and you have a query param named "country". To get this query param in a string format you can use the MEL to store this value in a variable as follows-

## [message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.country]

Your variable will look like

```html
<set-variable variableName="hello" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.country]" doc:name="Variable"/>
```

This would work, just try and reply.

Thanks,
Vibhor

Comment: My payload is already in String format. I need to do a POST call using HTTP component. You are suggesting to pass the payload as param in url?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below :-

```
    <set-variable variableName="Variable1" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Variable"/>
    <set-payload value="#[flowVars.Variable1]"  doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="test" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Am facing 1.Connection refused: no further information (java.net.ConnectException)
 sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl:-2 (null)   2.Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: String

Comment: How do I check in mule whether payload is actually posted in http ?

Comment: First try connecting that url using postman or soap. then try connecting in mule. Keeping logger before the http connector and logging the payload gives you what you are posting

Comment: This is the response is postman. Header : 
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
Body : Resource not found